# JavaScript - Random numbers and variables between functions

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am new to JavaScript, I have two roll functions for each roll of a frame. I am unable to get the values of each of those rolls into a frame function to call on and use. If someone could help this would be great! thanks in advance, My code is below.

```
var Bowling = function() {
  var STARTING_TOTAL = 0;
  ROLL_ONE = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  ROLL_TWO = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  this.score = STARTING_TOTAL;
  var firstScore;
  var secondScore;
  var totalScore;

  Bowling.prototype.firstRoll = function() {
     firstScore = ROLL_ONE
     return firstScore;
  };

  Bowling.prototype.secondRoll = function() {
     secondScore =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 - firstScore);
     return secondScore;

  };

  Bowling.prototype.frameScore = function () {
     totalScore = firstScore + secondScore
    return totalScore;
  };
```

};

Comment: You're never calling `firstRoll` and `secondRoll`. Those are functions. They need to be called. Once you call them, the return value then give you will be the roll you're looking for.

Comment: How do you want to use `Bowling`? As a class, I guess? Where do you call the methods?

Comment: Also, what is even the point of those functions? All they do is change a member variable to another member variable.

Comment: sorry I am a little confused, week into learning JavaScript. Yes using Bowling as a class, then looking to use the methods for different parts of my program to integrate with html for a small web app for a project.

Comment: @Carcigenicate what do you mean I am not calling firstRoll and secondRoll? in my frameScore? if not how do I that with keeping the same random numbers generated? thanks

Comment: @PeterMader yes I am using bowling as a class and the methods to use when I create my html pages. thanks

Comment: @SpencerBarton-fisher Do you know what it means to call a function?

Comment: `secondScore =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 - firstScore)` is super weird. Do you mean `secondScore =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) - firstScore`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I believe so. It would be what Peter has done below by console.log my functions? any functions I have created I would then have to call the function for it to run.

Comment: @YongQuan, the way I did before does work, I guess your version is better practise?

Comment: @PeterMader thank you very much for refactoring my code. I have been banging my head against a brick wall all day!!

Comment: @SpencerBarton-fisher Yes. Functions are basically reusable bits of code that you can use in many places. They need to be called though before they can be used. The code inside `firstRoll` isn't executed unless you write `firstRoll()`. Read more on functions. They're extremely important to understand.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for your advice I will read up on functions now. The code below does not work unfortunately, it is giving minus numbers as it is taking away rollOne from rollTwo. I am looking for roll two to be a random number between 10 - whatever roll one was.

Comment: It is the first time I have ever posted on stack overflow. I really appreciate all the help and such quick responses too!

Comment: @SpencerBarton-fisher Well, if the second roll is smaller than the first roll, the result will be negative. What result would you expect if the first roll was say `5.5`, and the second roll was `4.4`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate What I am looking for is roll one will be random out of 10, roll two will be random from the remainder of 10 - roll one. This is what I was trying to achieve with this.secondScore = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 - this.firstScore);. a frame in bowling is max 10 so roll two can only be max random number of 10 - roll one.

Comment: @SpencerBarton-fisher I added an answer. Note though, that this is questing is veering offtopic for the site, as getting general help about code really isn't what this site is for. I'll gladly help, as I think these are topic that's it's important to learn, but keep in mind for future questions, they should be very specific, and about a single issue. If you have another question, post it as another, new question.

Comment: @Carcigenicate really appreciate the help. My first time actually asking a question but noted for the future!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what you're trying to achieve. I refactored you code a little bit:

```js
var Bowling = function () {
  var STARTING_TOTAL = 0;
  this.score = STARTING_TOTAL; // remains unused; did you mean "totalScore"?
  this.firstScore = 0;
  this.secondScore = 0;
};

Bowling.prototype.firstRoll = function () {
  this.firstScore = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  return this.firstScore;
};

Bowling.prototype.secondRoll = function () {
  this.secondScore = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 - this.firstScore);
  return this.secondScore;

};

Bowling.prototype.frameScore = function () {
  this.totalScore = this.firstScore + this.secondScore
  return this.totalScore;
};

// now use it like this:
var bowling = new Bowling();
console.log(bowling.firstRoll());
console.log(bowling.secondRoll());
console.log(bowling.frameScore());
```

In my approach however, `firstScore` and `secondScore` are public properties.

Comment: firstly @PeterMader thanks for your help. when I call firstRoll on your code it is telling me it is not a function? (My apologies I am sure I am not being as clear as I wish I could be)

Comment: I am using StartingTotal as my starting score of 0 @PeterMader.

Comment: When writing "unused", I meant the `score` property, I guess `score` and `totalScore` are the same. And the error: here in the StackOverflow snippet it works. Do you use the class `Bowling` the same way I do? Or do you call it like this: `Bowling.firstRoll()` (which is different from `bowling.firstRoll()`)?

Comment: That happens :D

Answer (score 0):

To address the question of why the second roll can be negative: as your code currently stands, if the second roll is smaller than the first roll, the result will be negative. If you want it so that if the first roll is 6, the second roll will be a number between 0 and 4, try something like:

```js
function randomInt(maxNum) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum)
}
    
var maxRoll = 11
    
var rollOne = randomInt(maxRoll)
var rollTwo = randomInt(maxRoll - rollOne)
    
console.log(rollOne)
console.log(rollTwo)
```

Press "Run Code Snippet" over and over again to see it work.

Changes I've made:

- I made a function, `randomInt` that gives a random number from 0 to some max number. This saves you from needing to write the same code twice.
- I created a variable `maxRoll` that keeps track of what the highest possible roll is.
- I subtract `maxRoll` from the first roll to determine what the max number for the second roll should be (`maxRoll - rollOne`). That's then given to `randomInt`.